# Eslint error with Array forEach iteration: Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I'm trying to write a function to do transformation for Files which are not throwing any exception like a method below. I'm seeing ESLint error - "Eslint: Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.". What can be done to fix this eslint?

Note we would skip the files which will throw Error. Those are appropriately logged though.

```
export async function createDataFromFiles(inputFiles: File[]): Promise<Data[]> {
        const result: Data = [];
    
        inputFiles.forEach(
            async (file) => {
                const imageData = new DataView(await file.arrayBuffer());
                const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([imageData]));
                try {
                    const dimension = await getDimensionsFromImageUrl(blobUrl);
                    answer.push({ imageData, dimension });
                } finally {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
                }
            }
        );
    
        return Promise.all(answer);
    }
```

Comment: You could use an ordinary `for ... of` loop.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the signature of `Array.forEach`:

`forEach(callbackfn: (value: undefined, index: number, array: undefined[]) => void): void`.

The `callbackFn` has type `void`, but when using `async` the function implicitly returns a `Promise`.

You can avoid this warning by using an ordinary `for...of` loop:

```
export async function createDataFromFiles(inputFiles: File[]): Promise<Data[]> {
    const result: Data = [];

    for (const file of inputFiles) {
        const imageData = new DataView(await file.arrayBuffer());
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([imageData]));
        try {
            const dimension = await getDimensionsFromImageUrl(blobUrl);
            answer.push({ imageData, dimension });
        } finally {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
        }
    }

    return Promise.all(answer);
}
```